# AnyLogic PyCommunicator Run hello world

Tags: python, java, anylogic

When using the PyCommunicator. I can not import any python programs.

`pyCommunicator.run("import anylogic_try");`

When using this code AnyLogic throws the following:
Error during model startup:

root.pyCommunicator:

Failed to run python code; feedback: ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'anylogic_try'")

I am using Python 3.9.6 which is also used by the pyCommunicator.

Basically I want to run a python hello world in AnyLogic.

What should I do differently?

Comment: You have a lot of pieces here, and it's not at all clear what you're doing.  AnyLogic is a web service, which runs on a separate computer.  `pyCommunicator` is just a module that enables communication with another machine.  So, are you trying to use pyCommunicator ON the AnyLogic machine, or are you trying to use it to TALK TO AnyLogic?